# Java How to improve reading of 50 Gigabit file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I am reading a 50G file containing millions of rows separated by newline character. Presently I am using following syntax to read the file

```
String line = null;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("FileName")));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
// Processing each line here
// All processing is done in memory. No IO required here.
}
```

Since the file is too big, it is taking 2 Hrs to process the whole file. Can I improve the reading of file from the harddisk so that the IO(Reading) operation takes minimal time. The restriction with my code is that I have to process each line sequential order.

Comment: What is the implementation of Java's `BufferedReader`?  Perhaps you can improve there by reading blocks (with optimal size given the operating system and file system) in a different thread.

Comment: Do you mean 50 Gbit or 50 Gbyte?

Answer (score 9):

> it is taking 2 Hrs to process the whole file.

50 GB / 2 hours equals approximately 7 MB/s. It's not a bad rate at all. A good (modern) hard disk should be capable of sustaining higher rate continuously, so maybe your bottleneck is not the I/O? You're already using BufferedReader, which, like the name says, is buffering (in memory) what it reads. You could experiment creating the reader with a bit bigger buffer than the default size (8192 bytes), like so:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("FileName")), 100000);
```

Note that with the default 8192 bytes buffer and 7 MB/s throughput the BufferedReader is going to re-fill its buffer almost 1000 times per second, so lowering that number could really help cutting down some overhead. But if the processing that you're doing, instead of the I/O, is the bottleneck, then no I/O trick is going to help you much. You should maybe consider making it multi-threaded, but whether it's doable, and how, depends on what "processing" means here.

Comment: Yes, typical rates today are an order of magnitude higher *in benchmarks*. However, disk RPM, fragmentation etc. - and particularly other programs and OS doing their own stuff in the background - have tremendous effect. 10 MB/s sustained is not a bad real-world number for a 5 year old laptop.

Comment: I suppose you're right.  I guess I'm used to thinking about the disks that I tend to use at work, where 100MB/s sustained (in practice) is typical.

Comment: Yes, I've become somewhat conservative in my assumptions after finding some performance problems with my software being run in 10+ year old, worn computers ;) Also, some antivirus programs are particularly good at ruining any computer's I/O performance.

Comment: Note: If the program is I/O bounded multithreading would have almost no effect.

Comment: @razpeitia: that still depends on a lot of other things, there is minimal information known about the user's computer.

Comment: @razpeitia, actually multithreading may have adverse effect if reading from a single disk.

Answer (score 8):

Your only hope is to parallelize the reading and processing of what's inside.  Your strategy should be to never require the entire file contents to be in memory at once.

Start by profiling the code you have to see where the time is being spent.  Rewrite the part that takes the most time and re-profile to see if it improved.  Keep repeating until you get an acceptable result.

I'd think about Hadoop and a distributed solution.  Data sets that are larger than yours are processed routinely now.  You might need to be a bit more creative in your thinking.

Comment: Noted - I revisited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Without NIO you won't be able to break the throughput barrier. For example, try using `new Scanner(File)` instead of directly creating readers. Recently I took a look at that source code, it uses NIO's file channels.

But the first thing I would suggest is to run an empty loop with `BufferedReader` that does nothing but reading. Note the throughput -- and also keep an eye on the CPU. If the loop floors the CPU, then there's definitely an issue with the IO code.

Comment: Scanner uses heap buffers, not mapped direct buffers. So it's no very different than FileInputStream.read (still better since it doesn't require malloc/free on each read when the buffer is >8KB)

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable the antivirus and any other program which adds to disk contention while reading the file.
2. Defragment the disk.
3. Create a raw disk partition and read the file from there.
4. Read the file from an SSD.
5. Create a 50GB Ramdisk and read the file from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may get the best results by re-considering the problem you're trying to solve. There's clearly a *reason* you're loading this 50Gig file. Consider if there isn't a better way to break the stored data down and only use the data you really need.

Answer (score 0):

The way you read the file is fine. There might be ways to get it faster, but it usually requires understanding where your bottleneck is. Because the IO throughput is actually on the lower end, I assume the computation is having a performance side effect. If its not too lengthy you could show you whole program.

Alternatively, you could run your program without the contents of the loop and see how long it takes to read through the file :)